# Why is Apple using this "if let" code?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Apple has this segment of code on one of their sample projects:

```
    let existingImage = cache.objectForKey(documentIdentifier) as? UIImage

    if let existingImage = existingImage where cleanThumbnailDocumentIDs.contains(documentIdentifier) {
        return existingImage
    }
```

why is apple using this `if let`? Isn't more logical to simply use

```
    if cleanThumbnailDocumentIDs.contains(documentIdentifier) {
        return existingImage!
    }
```

???!!

Comment: Take a look at The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1) "The Basics" https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: You should avoid ! unless it is needed, because by definition every ! is a potential crash. if - let achieves that nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
  let existingImage = cache.objectForKey(documentIdentifier) as? UIImage

if let existingImage = existingImage where cleanThumbnailDocumentIDs.contains(documentIdentifier) {
    return existingImage
}
```

- This will make sure that if `existingImage == nil`,it will not
  execute `return existingImage`.
- Besides,`if let` also unwrap `existingImage` from `UIImage?` to
  `UIImage`

Comment: are you telling me that the insane  `let existingImage = existingImage` is unwrapping the optional? <s>I love when Apple makes things easy and obvious. </s>. Thanks

Comment: @SpaceDog: After the first ten uses you won't mind. After the first 20 uses you will love it.

Answer (score 1):

As Abhinav mentioned above, Apple introduced a new type called optional type with Swift.

What does optional mean?

Short and Sweet, "Optional types are types, which can contain a value of a particular data type or nil".

You can read more about optionals and their advantages here : [swift-optionals-made-simple](http://appventure.me/2014/06/13/swift-optionals-made-simple/)

Now whenever you want to make use of value present in an optional type, first you need to check what it contains i.e. does it contains a proper value or it contains nil. This process is called **optional unwrapping**.

Now there are two types of unwrapping,

1. Forced unwrapping : If you're sure that an optional will have an value all the time, you can then unwrap the value present in the optional type using "**!**" mark. This is force unwrapping.
2. The one more way is to use **if let** expression, this is safe unwrapping, here you'll check in your program that, if optional has a value you will do something with it; if it doesn't contain value you'd do something else. A simple example is this (You can test this in play  ground:

   ```
   func printUnwrappedOptional (opt:String?) {


   if let optionalValue = opt { //here we try to assign opt value to optionalValue constant, if assignment is successful control enters if block


       println(optionalValue) // This will be executed only if optionalValue had some value
   }
   else {
       println("nil")
   }}
   var str1:String? = "Hello World" //Declaring an optional type of string and assigning it with a value

   var str2:String? //Declaring an optional type of string and not assigning any value, it defaults to nil

   printUnwrappedOptional(str1) // prints "Hello World"

   printUnwrappedOptional(str2) // prints "nil"
   ```

Hope this clears your question, read through the link given above it'll be more clear to you. Hope this helps. :)

**Edit**: In Swift 2.0, Apple introduced "**guard**" statements, once you're good with optionals go through this link, [guard statement in swift 2](http://www.codingexplorer.com/the-guard-statement-in-swift-2/). This is another way to deal with optionals.

Comment: Excellent explaination.  But did you miss a } somewhere?

Comment: Yep I did forget } while ending the function. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `if let`, makes sure that the object (`existingImage`) is not nil, and it unwraps it automatically, so you are sure inside the if that the condition is true, and the object is not nil, and you can use it without unwrap it `!`

Answer (score 0):

With Swift, Apple has introduced a new concept/type - Optional Type. I think you better go through [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

> Swift also introduces optional types, which handle the absence of a
>   value. Optionals say either “there is a value, and it equals x” or
>   “there isn’t a value at all”. Optionals are similar to using nil with
>   pointers in Objective-C, but they work for any type, not just classes.
>   Optionals are safer and more expressive than nil pointers in
>   Objective-C and are at the heart of many of Swift’s most powerful
>   features.

Answer (score 0):

`existingImage` is an optional (`as? UIImage`) and therefor needs to be unwrapped before used, otherwise there would be a compiler error. What you are doing is called forced unwrapping via `!`. Your program will crash, if `existingImage == nil` and is therefor only viable, if you are absolutely sure, that `existingImage` can't be nil

Answer (score 0):

*if let*  and *optional types* is more help where is there is changes to get nil values to void crashes and unwanted code executions.

In Swift 2.0,

> guard

will help us lot where our intention is clear not to execute the rest of the code if that particular condition is not satisfied